# exchange elements in stack with javascript

Tags: javascript, css, onclick, grid, z-index

I want elements to toggle their order as I click on them. It seems `z-index` value is always 1. I can't figure out with this fails:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <style>
    .conteneur {
        display: grid;
    }
    .contenus {
        grid-column: 1;
        grid-row: 1;
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
    }
    
    .premier {
        background-color: red;
        z-index: 0;
    }
    
    .second {
        background-color: green;
        z-index: 1;
    }
  </style>

  <script>
    function echange() {
        let elts = document.getElementsByClassName("contenus");
        for (let i=0; i < elts.length; i++) {
            let z = elts[i].style.zIndex;
            elts[i].style.zIndex = (z + 1) % 2;
        }
    }
  </script>

  <body>
    <div class="conteneur">
      <div class="contenus premier" onclick="echange()"></div>
      <div class="contenus second" onclick="echange()"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're reading `zIndex` from the inline style object, it's not connected to the stylesheet rules. Use `window.getComputedStyle` to get the value for `z`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There're several issues:

- You need to get the computed styles by `window.getComputedStyle` since the `z-index` is not an inline style.
- the `zIndex` is a string, so `z + 1` will end up `11`, you need to parse it into number by adding `+` in front of it before doing the calculation

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <style>
    .conteneur {
        display: grid;
    }
    .contenus {
        grid-column: 1;
        grid-row: 1;
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
    }
    
    .premier {
        background-color: red;
        z-index: 0;
    }
    
    .second {
        background-color: green;
        z-index: 1;
    }
  </style>

  <script>
    function echange() {
        let elts = document.getElementsByClassName("contenus");
        for (let i=0; i < elts.length; i++) {
            let z = getComputedStyle(elts[i]).zIndex;
            elts[i].style.zIndex = (+z + 1) % 2;
        }
    }
  </script>

  <body>
    <div class="conteneur">
      <div class="contenus premier" onclick="echange()"></div>
      <div class="contenus second" onclick="echange()"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```